# Google Material Icons showing text instead of icon

Tags: jquery, css, icons, google-material-icons

I don't want icon text to be displayed in case the page fails to load the icons library. For example the below code should display the invite person icon-

```
<i style="font-size:16px;color:grey" class="material-icons">person_add</i>
```

But when the page fails to load for some reason(like slow internet connection), the above code is showing text - "person_add" which looks very insulting. Is there any solution for this issue, I infact don't want the text to be appeared in any way even if the library is no present.

Comment: Could you just delete person_add?

Comment: Not familiar with Material Icons, but with FontAwesome, classes are used for icons. Are you sure that's not the case?

Comment: @Li357 Yes I am sure. https://material.io/tools/icons/

Comment: @rileyjsumner please for god sake

Comment: Display your header part.

Comment: @KorelK you mean in the library in the <head> section ? Here it is - <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your link:

```
<link href="fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"**;** rel="stylesheet">
```

Remove the `;` and add `https://` in the beginning of the `href`:

```
<head>    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">    
</head>
```

Comment: Still the issue persists

Comment: @KaranParte can you post your whole html page?

Answer (score 0):

First Clear Your cache
Then add the link in your head section like this

```
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Then in your body section add this

```
  <i style="font-size:16px;color:grey" class="material-icons">person_add</i>
```

it should look like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <!--your code-->

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--your code-->

</head>

<body>
  <!--your code-->

  <i style="font-size:16px;color:grey" class="material-icons">person_add</i>

  <!--your code-->

</body>

</html>
```